# how can add double image to?

Tags: python

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The error I'm getting is:

```
let images = [UIImage(named: "Image1")!, UIImage(named: "Image2")!, UIImage(named: "Image3")!]
let yPositions = [0, 204, 693.5, 1186.5]

for (index, image) in images.enumerate() {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    if let yPosition = yPositions[index] {
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(yPosition), 375, 395)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the content of the dict returned by `load_library(lib_fpath)`.

Comment: I fixed your whitespace, it was totally messed up. Please recheck.

Comment: Surely the `n=0` initializer has to go above the for-loop?

Comment: Also, you can probably replace all of `report_author_counts()` with `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be closer to what you intent to do.

Read the data into a dict and count the occurrences:

```
def count_authors(file_name):
     invert = {}
     for k, v in load_library(file_name).items():
        invert[v] = invert.get(v, 0) + 1
     return invert
```

Then write the data into another file:

```
def write_authors_counts(counts, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fobj:
        for name, count in counts.items():
            fobj.write('{}: {}\n'.format(name, count)
```

Put both functions together:

```
def report_author_counts(lib_fpath, rep_filepath):
    counts = count_authors(lib_fpath)
    write_authors_counts(counts, rep_filepath))
```

Call your function:

```
write_authors_counts('file.txt', 'report.txt'))
```

Comment: thanks now i  understand my mistake it worked well but i want to add 'TOTAL BOOKS' when i sum the values all together which is 8 as above but i coudn't do it i think am close...i tried this def report_author_counts(lib_fpath, rep_filepath):
    with open(rep_filepath,'rt') as f:
        invert = {}
        z=0
        for k, v in load_library(lib_fpath).items():
            invert[v] = invert.get(v, 0) + 1
            z+=invert.get(None,0) +1
        return invert,'TOTAL BOOKS:',z
print(report_author_counts('books.txt','report.txt'))

Comment: why i am getting error when i try it with the automatic evaluation

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'report.txt'

Comment: How about putting this missing file in the same directory as the script?

Comment: can i make my function in a different way because the automatic evaluation doesn't accept it

Comment: Added a different version. Looks like you want write the result into a different file.

Comment: thanks that working but they asked for one function only for report i updated my question above with the whole question from my book

Comment: Just call both from function from another. Updated.

Comment: thanks it worked but when i try the automatic evaluation its says error..File report.txt contains 0 lines, but shall contain 1 lines.

Comment: when i changed the parameter of the load_library(f) to load_library(book_author) it worked